# How to merge several dataset using merge()

Tags: merge

I am trying three datasets - all from the same dataset filtering based on parameter:

1. dataset visdata where parameter='T_CDAI'; also rename the variable aval as cdaib and keeping the variables usubjid, parameter, cdaib, trtn
2. dataset visdata where parameter='T_NLVSS'; also rename the variable aval as sfb_ and keeping the variables usubjid, parameter, sfb_, trtn
3. dataset visdata where parameter='T_APSS'; also rename the variable aval as apb_ and keeping the variables usubjid, parameter, apb_, trtn

I can accomplish this in one SAS data step.

In R, I can also accomplish this by creating three dataset filtering by parameter and merging with several data steps

Questions:

1. Can I merge three datasets in one merge() function in R?
2. Can I combine all these tasks using filter and pipe in R?